# Windows Error After Wubi Install

Tags: windows-7, wubi

The initial install on my laptop was Windows 7.  I installed Wubi on Sunday - the install seemed fine.  I was able to log in and use both Ubuntu and Windows.

On Monday I started receiving the following error in Windows:  windows cannot access the specified device path or file

This occurs on every link I click on - essentially rendering Windows unusable.  I do not experience the same problem when Windows is started up in safe mode.

I have tried numerous virus scans (Malware bytes, Avg, AdAware) and have removed various trojans etc.  Windows is still unusable.  Ubuntu seems fine so far.

My question is, can this error be attributed to the Wubi install?

Answer (score 0):

You installed Wubi pretty recently. You might try uninstalling it to see if the error goes away. (Or are you unable to uninstall software in Windows, as part of this problem?)

If it doesn't, that doesn't prove Wubi isn't responsible. But if it *does* go away, then that pretty much does prove Wubi is responsible (even if only by triggering some bug in Windows). In that case, this should be reported as a bug against the [Wubi project on Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/wubi).

If you decide to uninstall Wubi and the problem goes away, then one workaround might be for you to install Ubuntu [in the standard manner](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/install-ubuntu-desktop), alongside rather than inside your Windows system.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  What I really wanted to know was if anyone else had this same issue in Windows after installing Wubi.  Since windows doesn't work for me, I am relying in Ubuntu at the moment :)  I want to avoid uninstalling it and completely locking myself out.